# Edit Text And Count Down Timer in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext

I have a Counttimer and edittext on my app. I want write a number in edittext, and when I click button, then countdown timer will start, and the time is edittext variable. In XML, I have got an example number, because when I delete it, then it's not working. When I start countdown timer, then it works, but if I change edittext, then it uses the old edittext data. How can I solve my problem?

**pomodoro.XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".pomodoro"
    android:background="@drawable/backround_home">
   

    <
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittextcalisma"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"

            android:text="20"

            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:lines="1"



            />
   
 

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittextmola"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="5"


            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:lines="1"

            />
       
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/baslatbutton"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Başla"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="visible"

        />

    

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/pomodoro"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java.class**

```
public class pomodoro extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button baslat;
    EditText edittextcalisma,edittextmola;
    TextView textcalisma,textmola,pomodoro;
    CountDownTimer calisma,mola;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pomodoro);
        baslat = findViewById(R.id.baslatbutton);
        edittextcalisma = findViewById(R.id.edittextcalisma);
        edittextmola = findViewById(R.id.edittextmola);
        textcalisma = findViewById(R.id.textcalisma);
        textmola = findViewById(R.id.textmola);
        String timercalisma = edittextcalisma.getText().toString();
        String timermola = edittextmola.getText().toString();
        long calismapo = Long.parseLong(timercalisma) * 60000;
        long molapo = Long.parseLong(timermola) * 60000;
        pomodoro = findViewById(R.id.pomodoro);
        
        baslat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                pomodoro.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                calisma.start();

            }
        });




        calisma = new CountDownTimer(calismapo, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millis) {

                int minuted1 = (int) (millis / 1000) / 60;
                int secondd1 = (int) (millis / 1000) % 60;
                pomodoro.setText(minuted1 + ":" + secondd1);
                if (secondd1 < 10) {
                    pomodoro.setText(minuted1 + ":0" + secondd1);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                calisma.cancel();
                mola.start();
            }
        };
        mola = new CountDownTimer(molapo, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long molapo) {

                int minuted1 = (int) (molapo / 1000) / 60;
                int secondd1 = (int) (molapo / 1000) % 60;
                pomodoro.setText(minuted1 + ":" + secondd1);
                if (secondd1 < 10) {
                    pomodoro.setText(minuted1 + ":0" + secondd1);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                mola.cancel();
                pomodoro.setText("Bitti");
}
        };


    }

   


}
```

Comment: Please elaborate correctly. What is expected and what is happening

Comment: ok can you wait

Comment: its ok can you look now

Comment: I didn't get what are you trying to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and the time is edittext variable. In XML, I have got an example
> number, because when I delete it, then it's not working.

Because you read your EditText fields in the onCreate and your code expects a number, then that is why you need to set the "example" numbers in XML.

When you remove the number from XML, you either need to:

check for null

```
    String timercalisma = edittextcalisma.getText().toString();
    String timermola = edittextmola.getText().toString();
    if(timercalisma == null || timercalisma.isEmpty()) {
        timercalisma = "0";
    }
    if(timermola == null || timermola.isEmpty()) {
        timermola = "0";
    }
    long calismapo = Long.parseLong(timercalisma) * 60000;
    long molapo = Long.parseLong(timermola) * 60000;
```

or read the fields on button press

```
    baslat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String timercalisma = edittextcalisma.getText().toString();
            String timermola = edittextmola.getText().toString();
            long calismapo = Long.parseLong(timercalisma) * 60000;
            long molapo = Long.parseLong(timermola) * 60000;
            pomodoro.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            calisma.start();

        }
    });
```

Comment: It can be late but thank you . How can ı add pause , finish countdown timer on button pressed @Blundell

Comment: I add 2 button for finish and pause . @Blundell

Comment: For finish, use `calisma.cancel()`, for pause, use the time you can in `onTick` and do a `cancel` and a `start` (start with the time you last saved in onTick).

Comment: calisma.cancel() , cant work . When ı cancel calisma then my app is close

Comment: Can you look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64963304/countdown-timer-finish-pause-in-android-studio) . @Blundell

Comment: Look at your logs as to why your app closes (read crashes), and fix that. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat